# If $G$ cubic planar graph with faces only $C_5$ and $C_6$, then $G$ has $12$ pentagons and $0$ hexagons

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I want to prove the questions in the title:

If $G$ is a connected cubic planar graph composed of only pentagons and hexagons, then it has $12$ pentagons and $0$ hexagons.

I was able to show it has $12$ pentagons, from Euler formula. However I am unable to proceed.

I believe it has to do with an inner structure it forms, because simply counting degrees and using Euler formula does not seem to work

Comment: Is that a planar graph? I say that because this is a question from a book, so I expect it to be true?

Comment: What about a soccer ball?

Answer (score 1):

The [Truncated icosahedral graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron#/media/File:Truncated_icosahedral_graph.png) has 12 pentagonal faces and 20 hexagonal faces. As noted in Wikipedia, it is connected, cubic, Hamiltonian, regular and, of course, it is planar. See also the [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatedIcosahedralGraph.html) article.

Comment: I really do not see any problem with this. However, it is clearly contradicting the exercise in the book... I guess I should accept you answer then?

Comment: I don't know what is the context of the exercise, but it is very likely that it is wrong. About accepting my answer, there is no rush.

Comment: Okay! I will check back with the professor that is lecturing my class and come back to accept it if there is nothing else to it.